# Catch exception and output them to django's messages system

Tags: python, django, exception

So I noticed that Django has a nice message framework. It has 5 different levels (info, error, debug, warning, and success).

It would be really nice to propagate the exception all the way up to the views level, and report some of these exceptions.

lib.py

```
def read_file(user, filename, **kwargs):
   try:
     with open(...):
        return f.read()
   except Exception, e:
     raise e
```

utli.py

```
def wrapper_read_file(user, filename, **kwargs):
   try:
      if user.is_authenticated and user.belongs('admin'):
          lib.read_file(...)
      else:
          raise Exception("Unauthenticated user!!!")
   except Exception, e:
      raise e
```

views.py

```
def my_view(request):
   [..] do something here
   try:
     result = wrapper_read_file(...)
     return render(request, 'hello.html', {'result': result})
   except Exception, e:
     if isinstance(e, IOError):
         if e.errno==errno.ENOENT:
         messages.add_message(request, message.ERROR, 'File does not exist.')
     elif isinstance(e, OSError):
         messages.add_message(request, message.ERROR, 'You don't have sufficient permission to open the file.')
     return render(request, 'hello.html', {'hello_world': 'hello_world'}
```

Django knows how to render the `messages` and I have the facility to do that. So it will display `messages`.

Do you think my exception handling looks reasonable? Any alternative suggestions? I am pretty new to Python error exception handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want to catch *every* exception. This may mask other errors, and will do things like prevent Ctrl-C from working. Instead, catch only the exceptions you want to handle.

```
try:
    # action that may throw an exception
except IOError, e: # Will only catch IOErrors
    if e.errno == errno.ENOENT:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, "File not found")
    else:
        raise e    # Re-raise other IOErrors
except OSError, e: # Will only catch OSErrors
    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, "Insufficient permissions")

return render(request, 'hello.html', {})
```

**Update**: added a second except clause to handle other another exception type. Note that this is still probably insufficient, as this makes the (big) assumption that *all* `OSErrors` are permissions related.

Comment: Schinkckel Thank you. Sorry for the late response. In your snippet, are you suggesting that I should only catch the specific exception at the caller level, and let the rest of the callee to just `raise Exception`? Is `Exception as e` a good exception catching? Suppose A calls B, B calls C, C calls D, under what condition would I want to catch specific exceptions at level B, C, besides at A (like the snippet, A could be our view function).? Lastly, how does my original code `mask other errors` if they fail in the `else` clause?

Comment: In your views.py, you catch every exception, and then test against some exception types before finally rendering. You are not testing against all of the possible exception types, and so it is possible that you have another exception being generated, and then you are rendering the page as if there were none. This also bypasses any middleware exception handling (which is really a better way to do this).